# Django REST Framework: creating hierarchical objects using URL arguments

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a django-rest-framework REST API with hierarchical resources. I want to be able to create subobjects by POSTing to `/v1/objects/<pk>/subobjects/` and have it automatically set the foreign key on the new subobject to the `pk` kwarg from the URL without having to put it in the payload. Currently, the serializer is causing a 400 error, because it expects the `object` foreign key to be in the payload, but it shouldn't be considered optional either. The URL of the subobjects is `/v1/subobjects/<pk>/` (since the key of the parent isn't necessary to identify it), so it is still required if I want to `PUT` an existing resource.

Should I just make it so that you POST to `/v1/subobjects/` with the parent in the payload to add subobjects, or is there a clean way to pass the `pk` kwarg from the URL to the serializer? I'm using `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` and `ModelViewSet` as my respective base classes. Is there some recommended way of doing this? So far the only idea I had was to completely re-implement the ViewSets and make a custom Serializer class whose get_default_fields() comes from a dictionary that is passed in from the ViewSet, populated by its kwargs. This seems quite involved for something that I would have thought is completely run-of-the-mill, so I can't help but think I'm missing something. Every REST API  I've ever seen that has writable endpoints has this kind of URL-based argument inference, so the fact that django-rest-framework doesn't seem to be able to do it at all seems strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the parent object serializer field read_only. It's not optional but it's not coming from the request data either. Instead you pull the pk/slug from the URL in `pre_save()`...

```
# Assuming list and detail URLs like:
#   /v1/objects/<parent_pk>/subobjects/
#   /v1/objects/<parent_pk>/subobjects/<pk>/
def pre_save(self, obj):
    parent = models.MainObject.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['parent_pk'])
    obj.parent = parent
```

Comment: `pre_save` doesn't get called until after deserialization, at which point it has already thrown a validation error.

Comment: That is one option and would work for something like comments, but some of the objects I have should be able to be reparented, so setting the parent explicitly in a PUT would be nice too. On the other hand, I could do it this way and then have an explicit 'reparent' POST action or something, but that seems a little less RESTful. I'll accept this answer since it's a good idea and will work for the majority of cases.

Comment: With django rest 3.x pre_save is no longer available.  I succeeded in using `perform_create()` in the view.  See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've done to solve it, although it would be nice if there was a more general way to do it, since it's such a common URL pattern. First I created a mixin for my ViewSets that redefined the `create` method:

```
class CreatePartialModelMixin(object):
    def initial_instance(self, request):
        return None

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.initial_instance(request)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            instance=instance, data=request.DATA, files=request.FILES,
            partial=True)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.pre_save(serializer.object)
            self.object = serializer.save(force_insert=True)
            self.post_save(self.object, created=True)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(
                serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                headers=headers)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Mostly it is copied and pasted from `CreateModelMixin`, but it defines an `initial_instance` method that we can override in subclasses to provide a starting point for the serializer, which is set up to do a partial deserialization. Then I can do, for example,

```
class SubObjectViewSet(CreatePartialModelMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # ....

    def initial_instance(self, request):
        instance = models.SubObject(owner=request.user)
        if 'pk' in self.kwargs:
            parent = models.MainObject.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
            instance.parent = parent
        return instance
```

(I realize I don't actually need to do a `.get` on the pk to associate it on the model, but in my case I'm exposing the slug rather than the primary key in the public API)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `ModelSerializer` (which is implemented by `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`) it's as easy as implementing the `restore_object()` method:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):

        if instance is None:
            # If `instance` is `None`, it means we're creating
            # a new object, so we set the `parent_id` field.
            attrs['parent_id'] = self.context['view'].kwargs['parent_pk']

        return super(MySerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)

    # ...
```

`restore_object()` is used to deserialize a dictionary of attributes into an object instance. `ModelSerializer` [implements this method](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L924) and creates/updates the instance for the model you specified in the `Meta` class. If the given `instance` is `None` it means the object still has to be created, so you just add the `parent_id` attribute on the `attrs` argument and call `super()`.

So this way you don't have to specify a read-only field, or have a custom view/serializer.

More information:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#declaring-serializers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but i guess [this drf nested routers library](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) could be helpful for that operation.